# Except in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have encountered the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:664)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:645)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:625)
    at KConsumer.main(KConsumer.java:19)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:730)
    ... 4 more
```

[image]

Comment: Please prefer copy/paste your code instead of [posting it as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As the error says, Kafka isn't running at the address provided. How about starting with the console consumer?

Comment: I will keep in mind "to not post code as picture"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an ***s*** in `bootstrap.servers` property. Try using `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig` class to get proper properties name.

Comment: thanks can't believe its was a typo mistake ...thank you very much